# Cocoapods errors in Xcode building AR App in Unity 3D using cloud anchors

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, cocoapods, augmented-reality

I’ve run into a problem that I hope someone can help me with.

I’m building an iOS AR App in Unity, my App works fine, but I’ve decided to use ARCore CloudAnchors, so I’ve imported ARCore Extensions and installed cocoapods through Terminal with - sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4 and I’ve set up a API Key through the API and Services in the Google cloud.

And everything was building fine until I put my API Key into Unity and built my project.

I went into Project Settings/XR Plug-in Management/ARCore Extensions and ticked iOS Support Enabled, chose iOS Authentication Strategy as API Key, pasted my API Key into iOS API Key field, ticked Optional Fields Cloud Anchors.

Then I built my project and now Xcode throws up three errors the first is -

/Users/kevingriffiths/Desktop/Unity builds/AR World Anchors/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj Signing for "ARCore-ARCoreResources" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.

So I set that to mine mine and rebuild, it passes the first error then the next error is -

/Users/kevingriffiths/Desktop/Unity builds/AR World Anchors/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.0.99.

Even though In my project setting its set to 16, I set that to 16 and build again, passes the first and second errors then comes the third error -

Framework 'ARCoreBase.xcframework' not found

This is the one I can’t get passed, I’ve been to the build folder and opened Terminal and tried -

arch -x86_64 pod update
arch -x86_64 pod install
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

And I’m still getting the errors when building, I’m working on a M1 iMac macOS Ventura 13.5.2

If I disable iOS Support Enabled in ARCore Extensions, delete the build folder and build again it builds and works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Kevin.

EDIT -
Ive added the ARCoreBase.xcframework, cleaned the build folder, re built, and I'm still getting the error -
Framework 'ARCoreBase.xcframework' not found

[image: Error]

EDIT -
A copy of the error

[image]